# IE7 CSS table header borders not aligning to tbody cells

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

I have a requirement to have a scrolling table in both x and y axis.

I achieved this by cloning the existing table header into a new table with jQuery.

I have mocked the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PaQne/1/

In IE7 the borders of the cloned thead cells do not align with the parent thbody cells even though the CSS is the same.

Is there a fix for this?

I appreciate that this is not best practice and IE7 is a dying browser but it is a client requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing this rule:

```
.grid-cntr .data-grid thead {
    display: none;
}
```

made the borders align. But obviously you want to hide the thead on IE7 too, so let's use an hack!

```
.grid-cntr .data-grid thead {
    display: none;
    *display:block; /* target IE7 and below only */
}
```

Then, add this rule:

```
.grid-cntr .data-grid {
    *margin-top:-32px;
}
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/fn7gb/)**

Otherwise, if you want to keep your code "clean", you can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Add this code to your head section, *after* the normal css:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style>
.grid-cntr .data-grid thead { display:block; }
grid-cntr .data-grid { margin-top:-32px; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

---

Anyway, you're using `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors, but check this [compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html):

1. `last-child` won't work on IE7 and 8 **at all**
2. `first-child` works only on **static elements**, not on generated contents

Try to use classes instead, if you need full compatibility with IE7+.

There's also [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) which does a great job for CSS3 selectors on older IE versions.

---

Then you've this rule:

```
.data-grid td:first-child {
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
```

are you aware that this rule will overwrite that on the last row?

```
.data-grid tr:last-child td {
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
}
```

Maybe you want to use

```
.data-grid td:first-child {
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional tips but it does really tackle the problem in hand.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what you're seeing? I only see 1px difference on IE7, but i'm using [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Comment: It is the 1px that i need to fix :)